# How can I not get logged out with a CakePHP application running on Heroku?

Tags: cakephp, heroku

Essentially, I host a CakePHP site on Heroku, but whenever I do a Git push to update the site, all my users get logged out.

I'm assuming it has to do with the `/tmp` folder which gets refreshed everytime you do an update on Heroku. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: The /tmp folder gets destroyed when the dyno cycles (about every 24 hours) and doesn't contain the same info across dynos. Anything that needs to persist in your app should be in an external backing service: data, necessary session info, cache etc

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change the cache provider to either `database` or `cache` (memcached) as described in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration

This will also have the advantage of working if you scale to multiple dynos (which won't share a /tmp folder)